# Browser.msgBox() times out when multiple boxes are open (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google Sheet, and there are cases in my `onEdit()` function where a `Browser.msgBox()` appears. It's possible to have multiple boxes appear at once (due to lag with `onEdit()`), and the user can see only one of the boxes. When they dismiss it, it goes away.

Six minutes later, the other `msgBoxes` will throw an error because of a time-out (even though there is no way for the user to see them or dismiss them).

This is problematic for trigger computation time. Anyone else experiencing this? FWIW, I find this to be the case with `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()` as well.

Comment: Try `LockService`

Comment: There can't be multiple occurrences of UI messages, you should prevent this to occur.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to prevent this from happening. It happens when two or more onEdits are called before the first onEdit renders the box. Are you suggesting I use LockService whenever an onEdit happens? Is there a cost to performance?

Comment: @user5042616 of course there is. Code that needs the lock to run will either time out (waiting for the lock), or not run until after it gets the lock. In all cases there is a delay now, where there was not one previously. Your application design should be robust to this delay.